# how to do group by in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm writing a hive query in which I need to group by a few field however I need to select some other fields besides those exist in the group by statement. That is,

```
select A,B,C from table_name GROUP BY A,B
```

HIVE complains and says `Invalid table alias or column reference C`. It requires me to put `C` in the GROUP BY part but that changes my logic. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: what is your problem statement for using group by?

Comment: Do you have valid column C ?
The error message seems not related to `group by`

Answer (score 4):

[HIVE-Select-statement-and-group-by-clause](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+GroupBy#LanguageManualGroupBy-Selectstatementandgroupbyclause) - group by must be used with some aggregate function like count, sum etc.

so there must be one of  the aggregate calculation on column `C`

example:

```
select A,B,count(C) as Total_C from table_name GROUP BY A,B;
select A,B,SUM(C) as Total_C from table_name GROUP BY A,B;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to join after group by.

```
select T1.*, t2.c from (select a,b, count(*) as SomeAggFunc from table group by a,b) T1;
<join condition> table t2 on t1.a=t2.a and t1.b=t2.b
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: My understanding from question was he want the aggregation result based on group by columns a and b and in output col c as well, with join after group by we can get this result

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `cluster by` instead of `group by`

```
select A,B,C from table_name CLUSTER BY A,B
```